# Make distutils place compiled extensions in the right folder

Tags: python, distutils

I wrote a Python C extension that I'm building with distutils. This is `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

utilsmodule = Extension('utils', sources = ['utilsmodule.c'])

setup (name = 'myPackage',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'My package',
       ext_modules = [utilsmodule])
```

When I run `python setup.y build`, the extension is built correctly but the `.pyd` file goes into the folder `build/lib.win-amd64-3.7`, and not into the module's root where Python looks for modules to import. I need to move that file out of `build` after building to be able to import it.

I thought about adding a line after `setup()` that moves the file, but that seems a bit dirty, I'm guessing that distutils should do that work.

What is the right way to compile an extension in a way that it can be imported by other Python files immediately after build?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `install` phase after `build`?

Comment: @phd Maybe, I'm not familiar with distutils. I don't want to install this system-wide, it's just part of a script for a research project. I use distutils because it seems to be the recommended way to compile extensions.

Comment: Well, [tag:setuptools] is the recommended way. And [tag:virtualenv] is the recommended way to separate libraries from the system-wide installation.

Comment: @phd is that really necessary? setuptools seems to do everything I don't need (packaging, installing, upgrading) and virtualenv's doc says it puts an entire Python install in my application folder, when all I want is to build a single C extension and call its functions from my script. No one else is going to use this. Sorry if I'm missing something, I'm not used to C extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> distutils should do that work.

It shouldn't. Building is just an intermediate phase to packaging, installing and using.

> What is the right way to compile an extension in a way that it can be imported by other Python files immediately after build?

There is no such a way. You can set `%PYTHONPATH%` to point to `build/lib.win-amd64-3.7` and import the module directly from `build/`.

Or you may try to bend distutils:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext
import os

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def run(self):
        _build_ext.run(self)
        os.rename("build/lib.win-amd64-3.7/%s" % mypydname, dest_dir)

setup(
    …
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    …
)
```

but any way you have to decide where to move the compiled module.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update the info in 2022~

If you want to test your module inside the project you develop your package, I think changing the extension name and then using `--inplace` flag is enough.

For example, if `this_package` is your extension, and you want your package structure to be like:

```
project_dir
    |-- package
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- this_package.xxxx.so
    |   |-- other.py
    |-- setup.py
```

You can just set the name of this extension like:

```py
Extension("package.this_package", source_files)
```

And then build it by:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

If you want to distribute and publish the package, and you want the structure of the installed package to be also like the above one.

1. If you're open to sharing your source files, you could use `python setup.py sdist` to create the `.tar.gz` distribution. If all the source files are gathered in the `.tar.gz` file (by configuring `setup.py`). The package would be correctly built on the target machine and then installed in the `site-packages` directory with such a structure.
2. If not, you might need to use `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or something to build a binary wheel for publishing. It would build the library locally and (I think) we are able to publish only the `.so` library. However, the `.whl` is OS+Arch dependent, so you might need to build multiple distributions for different OS+Arch.

Whatever way we use, by setting the name `package.this_package` for the extension, you could always have the `.so` at the proper place.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the name of the extension to `<path>.<to>.<package>.<extension_name>` will place it in the directory that you want.  For example:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

utilsmodule = Extension('package.utils', sources = ['utilsmodule.c'])

setup (name = 'myPackage',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'My package',
       ext_modules = [utilsmodule])
```

Will place the `utils` extension under the `package` package